# Calling `clock()` gives an error: undefined reference to `_times'

Tags: c++, embedded, clock, atmelstudio

I'm trying to use the `clock()` function in my C++ code but it's not working. I've tried adding `#include <time.h>` or `#include <ctime>` but it hasn't helped. I'm using Atmel Studio.

```
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
        clock_t myClock = clock();
}
```

There shouldn't be an error, but I'm getting the following error messages:

```
recipe for target 'SAMS70.elf' failed
undefined reference to `_times'
ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Perhaps you need to link to a particular static library.

Comment: `clock()` is often implemented on top of `clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID)` - so search for that too.

Comment: @TedLyngmo most likely, OP will end with the same result. Their C++ implementation seems to do everything correctly, but underlying `_times` is just not there because MCU has no way of providing this information.

Comment: @SergeyA You are probably right. It's worth a try though. Doesn't take many seconds(!) :-)

Comment: `clock()` has hardware dependencies so you are normally required to implement or override a non-functional implementation with your own code using available timing hardware on your target.  It is generally a very simple function to implement using an on-chip timer or sysclk interrupt.  Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335353/built-in-function-clock-not-working-in-atmel-studio-7-0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MCU's normally do not expose processor use time. A library `clock` function calls the expected `_times` function to get the value, but the function is not defined for MCU for the reason stated above.